# Shuffling rows in a Pandas DataFrame while retaining the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shuffle

I am currently trying to find a way to randomize items in a dataframe row-wise. I want to preserve the column names as well as the index. I just want to change the order of entries in my dataframe.

Currently, I was using

```
data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, this is causing some issues in terms of output. I don't think the rows are being shuffled properly. Is there another way to achieve that?

The issue is that I am doing text analysis and when I am looking at the most correlated unigrams and bigrams with each class, I am getting different answers for shuffled and original data.

This is the code I am using for monograms and bigrams

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, 
                    min_df=5, 
                    stop_words=STOPWORDS, 
                    norm = 'l2', 
                    encoding='latin-1', 
                    ngram_range=(1, 2))

feat = tfidf.fit_transform(data['Combine']).toarray()

N = 5    # Number of examples to be listed
for f, i in sorted(category_labels.items()):
    chi2_feat = chi2(feat, labels == i)
    indices = np.argsort(chi2_feat[0])
    feat_names = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names())[indices]
    unigrams = [w for w in feat_names if len(w.split(' ')) == 1]
    bigrams = [w for w in feat_names if len(w.split(' ')) == 2]
    print("\nFlair '{}':".format(f))
    print("Most correlated unigrams:\n\t. {}".format('\n\t. '.join(unigrams[-N:])))
    print("Most correlated bigrams:\n\t. {}".format('\n\t. '.join(bigrams[-N:])))
```

Comment: What are the issues with the output? What makes you think the rows aren't being shuffled? Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: Do you want to `reset_index` ? If you want to preserve the indexes, then just `data = data.sample(frac=1)` should be enough

Comment: Hi, I just made that edit. I hope this can make it more clear.

Comment: @NYCCoder Just using `data = data.sample(frac=1)` does not work because it samples the index as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `data = data.sample(frac=1)` samples the index as well and that is problematic. You can see the output below. We just need to change the values.

[image]

The correct method to achieve this is by just sampling the values. I just figured it out. We can do it this way. Thank you everybody who tried to help.

```
data[:] = data.sample(frac=1).values
```

I was getting the correct output from this.